# How to include java inside an application setup

Tags: java, windows-installer

I have created a java application. I have used **Launch4J** to create exe and **InnoSetup** to create the setup file for windows. Whenever I'm running my application on other system which has no java(pre-installed) is asking for to install java. I want to run my application without java installation.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/deploy/self-contained-application-packaging.htm

> This topic describes how to generate the package for a self-contained application. A self-contained application contains your Java or JavaFX application and the JRE needed to run the application. Self-contained packages can be created for distribution to systems running Linux, macOS, and Windows.